# How do I remove index.php from the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove the index.php from the url with .htaccess and I have come half way and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I have/using the following settings/system:

- Codeigniter 2.1.4
- Ubuntu 12.04
- `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/present';`
- apache2
- php5

When I'm trying the following urls:

`http://localhost/present/test` it displays the page. So far so good.

`http://localhost/present/index.php/test` it also displays the page so I get duplicate pages. And that is my problem.

I'm using the following .htaccess in the same folder as index.php.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Can some friendly soul tell me what is wrong? Is it the mod_rewrite or maybe some server/php settings that are wrong?

Comment: You're a bit vague on what you want your htaccess to do.

Comment: I want the htaccess to remove the index.php from the url. For example the following, original, url request localhost/present/index.php/test will be changed to localhost/present/test

Answer (score 0):

To make fancy url's, you'll need an internal rewrite (which you have) and an external redirect (which you don't have). The difficult part is not making an infinite loop.

If you are using Apache 2.3.9 or up, you can use the END-flag.

```
#Redirect
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ $1 [R,L]

#Internal Rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [END]
```

If you are using a lower version, you'll need to use a hack-ish workaround. THE_REQUEST will only be set like this on an actual request, not on an rewrite.

```
#Redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ $1 [R,L]

#Internal Rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [L]
```

Comment: I'm using Apache2 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4 and your example are not working at all I'm afraid. Now the `localhost/present/test` won't work. 

Getting the following error message (The requested URL /present/test was not found on this server.)

Comment: you might need to prepend "present/" to some of the parts

Comment: I don't have time to alter this or test this (have to leave the house for dinner), but I think you should set the RewriteBase to /present

Comment: Thanks for your help, but even when I write in RewriteBase /present it returns same error message, "The requested URL /present/admin was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no-redir
RewriteRule ^/?index.php/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0?no-redir [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, but it won't work. Getting following error message: "The requested URL /present/test was not found on this server."

Comment: Where is your htaccess located? Inside root?

Comment: Yeah, in the first folder "/" with the index.php file.

Comment: But, your url `http://localhost/present/index.php/test` suggests it's inside `/present`. Does it? And does `/present` actually exist? If it's at "/" shouldn't the url that works be `http://localhost/index.php/present/test`?

Comment: The site is under the folder `/srv/www/present/` and I have set base url in Codeigniter to `http://localhost/present/` So the .htaccess file are then located in the root/base folder `/srv/www/present/.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks for the time you are putting in to my problem Ravi, but I got same problem. `index.php` won't go away. `localhost/present/index.php/test` return same test function as before instead of removing the `index.php` from the url.

Comment: I think `$config['base_url']` could be interfering. Can you test once without it? If it still doesn't work can you add `[R=301,L]` to your `index.php/$0` rule and note down the actual url you're redirected to.

Comment: Still same, but I'm giving up. I will remove ubuntu and install OS X once again, I know that it will work there. Thanks anyway for your time and effort to solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I use this to redirect all requests to index.php