# Renaming and redirecting pages fails in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am sorry to ask this question, because the answer seemingly is so easy. However, after three hours of trial and error I am without a clue.

I have several pages on a website using parameters in the url. I would like to change that, to a more regular url. Example:

domain.com/pag.php?id=1-awesome-page should become domain.com/awesome-page

So far so good, but so far I have three problems.
 1. The old page still is accessible, Google will index it as duplicated content. When I try to redirect it, I am getting infinite loop errors.
 2. For whatever reason, sometimes SOME images (straight from the content) get stripped off on the newly named page. I tried playing with a base-url and renaming the images and urls, but nothing so far.
 3. Also the redirect doesn't care if i'd enter id=1-awesome-page or id=2-worthless-page. It all redirects to the first one.

Among the things i've tried.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1-awesome-page
RewriteRule ^pag\.php$ /awesome-page? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule  ^awesome-page?$     pag\.php?id=1  [NC]
```

Comment: are you deleting browser cache for the page after you make changes to `.htaccess`, i.e. is it possible the reason the old URL is still accessible is because your browser, is "remembering" it?

Comment: I tried closing and reopening the browser and good old CTRL+F5 but that didn't help.

Comment: thats a "hard" reload. To clear cache on chrome (just for that page you are working on) open developer tools,  then click and hold reload button until the option to clear cache appears - that will clear the cache - .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do cannot really be done with mod_rewrite, unless you want to make a rule for every page, which will probably slow your site down quite a lot. This is, because you can't summon the `1` in `1-awesome-page` out of thin air, and your pag.php page doesn't seem to be able to load the page only based on it's seo name. If you need to use that number, you need to have that number somewhere in your url.

As for your questions:

The error you mention cannot be reproduced with the current iteration of your .htaccess. You likely had an infinite loop previously, and since you use `R=301` to test, the browser will cache this redirect and only request the second resource afterwards when you request the first resource. You should test with `[R,L]` and only change to `[R=301,L]` when everything works as expected. Not doing so will cause weird behaviour, and behaviour you do not expect with your .htaccess.

When you have an url `a` and an url `b`, and want to redirect `a` to `b`, and want to internally rewrite `b` to `a`, you need to make sure that any given time not both rules can be matched. You can either use the `%{THE_REQUEST}` trick or use the `END` flag. Both are outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290091/how-do-i-remove-index-php-from-the-url/18290306#18290306).

If you have a problem with resources on a page not loading after making a fancy url, you likely used relative url's. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744603/css-js-and-images-do-not-display-with-pretty-url) outlines the possibilities on how to resolve this. You can either make the url's absolute or relative to the root of your site, or use `<base href="/">`.

---

The following would work for `/pag.php?id=123-news-page` and `/news/123/news-page`.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pag\.php\?.*id=([^-]+)-([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^pag\.php$ /news/%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteRule  ^news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ pag.php?id=$1-$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciated your help and explanation. I tried this, but whatever page i open, they all show the content of the very first one. Also images / css / etc are not working.

Comment: It can have several causes: You have more rules, and one of them is causing this behaviour. You previously tried something with a permanent redirect, and this causes the browser to cache the result. In this case, try with a different browser you haven't used to test. You are using a framework, and this framework looks at the url in the address bar rather than the url that is rewritten. This is, for example, the case with wordpress. Read the documentation of your framework if this might be the case.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. I cleared all rules, except for the ones you sent. I tried different browsers. The images seem to work now, the CSS for whatever reason still isn't.
I am using a custom framework that indeed relies on getting the ID (1 in the sample) from the URL. I'll try and feed the ID based on the rewritten url.

Comment: My Bad Sumurai, the ID fetching was horrible. Made this a long time ago. The CSS still isn't working, but I gave up on that. I just linked the whole URL and it's done. Thanks for the help, cheers!

Comment: Sumurai8 sorry to keep bugging you. But what should I do if I want to get rid of both "news" and the ID (int) in the URL. I tried deleted " news/" from your code and this seems to work, however, all images for whatever reason dissapear as well. The number (ID) I don't even come close to removing. It is safe though. The site is static, I just want to rename about 10 pages and that's it for now. No new pages will be added.